# How to make sure a correctly defined trading signal in pine editor v5 triggers a subsequent entry?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am currently working with pine editor v5 in tradingview to build a scalping strategy based on a heiken ashi overlay. To keep it simple, when a bunch of conditions is fulfilled based on the heiken ashi overlay, a buy or a sell signal is created during a specified session. As I have done with other strategies, I now want the creation of a trading signal to generate a subsequent entry via a strategy.entry function. The problem is, no matter how I am structuring the entry function (I am using ChatGPT 4 for help here), the signals are always displayed properly, yet on many days the entry function is not executed properly.

The snippet is this:

```
`// Logic for Signal Generation and Strategy Entries
if isSession
    if bearBBBPrinted and bullishNoWick
        bearBBBPrinted := false
        strategy.entry("Buy_" + str.tostring(bar_index), strategy.long)
        label.new(bar_index, low, "Buy Signal", color=color.blue, style=label.style_label_up)

    if bullBBBPrinted and bearishNoWick
        bullBBBPrinted := false
        strategy.entry("Sell_" + str.tostring(bar_index), strategy.short)
        label.new(bar_index, high, "Sell Signal",color=color.purple,style=label.style_label_down)`
```

The signal labels have been introduced only to visualize that the underlying logic is functioning properly, which it apparently does. Yet it does not always lead to an entry execution, and I cannot spot any reason for this.